# Два способа вызова результата функции

Tags: php

Есть два способа вызова результата функции.

Я не могу понять, есть ли между ними разница и какой из них лучше.

```
function callBack($numbers){  
$result = 0;
 
foreach($numbers as $items){
$result = $result + $items;
}
 
return $result ."<br>";
};
 
 
 
$massive1 = [1,2,3,4,5];  
$massive2 = [2,2,3,4,5];
 
echo callBack($massive1);       // первый способ вызова
 
$second = callBack($massive2);  // второй способ вызова результата
echo $second;
```

Comment: Лучше когда код покороче и  понятнее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Единственная разница между ними -- во втором случае результат работы функции записывается в переменную `$second`. Это нужно, если вам необходим результат еще в какой-то части кода. По сути больше никакой разницы.